# When is Avraham Avinu's Yahrzeit?

Tags: death, avot-patriarch-fathers, yahrtzeit

I have no sources to provide to this question. Rather I am asking simply. On what day was Avraham Avinu nifter? (pass away.) Do we know at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In [Rosh ha-Shanah 10b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=10b&format=pdf)-[11a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11&format=pdf), there is a *Machaloqet* between R. Eli'ezer and R. Yehoshu'a over when, amongst other events, the *Avot*( Avraham and Ya'aqov) died:

   > תניא **רבי אליעזר אומר** בתשרי נברא העולם בתשרי נולדו אבות **בתשרי מתו אבות** בפסח נולד יצחק בראש השנה נפקדה שרה רחל וחנה בראש השנה יצא יוסף מבית האסורין בר"ה בטלה עבודה מאבותינו במצרים בניסן נגאלו בתשרי עתידין ליגאל
   >   **ר' יהושע אומר** בניסן נברא העולם בניסן נולדו אבות **בניסן מתו אבות** בפסח נולד יצחק בר"ה נפקדה שרה רחל וחנה בר"ה יצא יוסף מבית האסורין בר"ה בטלה עבודה מאבותינו במצרים בניסן נגאלו בניסן עתידין ליגאל

   In English( from the Soncino translation, p.25-26 in the PDF, download-able [here](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Rosh_HaShanah.pdf)):

   > It has been taught: **R. Eliezer says**: In Tishri the world was created; in Tishri the Patriarchs were born; **in Tishri the Patriarchs died**; on Passover Isaac was born; on New Year Sarah, Rachel and Hannah were visited; on New Year Joseph went forth from prison; on New Year the bondage of our ancestors in Egypt ceased; in Nisan they were redeemed and in Nisan they will be redeemed in the time to come.
   >   **R. Joshua says**: In Nisan the world was created; in Nisan the Patriarchs were born; **in Nisan the Patriarchs died**; on Passover Isaac was born; on New Year Sarah, Rachel and Hannah were visited; on New Year Joseph went forth from prison; on New Year the bondage of our ancestors ceased in Egypt; and in Nisan they will be redeemed in time to come.
2. R. Shimshon ben Pesach Ostropoli, in his commentary *Dan Yadin* to *Sefer Qarnayim*( a Kabbalistic work, which R. Shimshon attributes to R. Aharon ben Avraham of Kardina), says( in [Ma'arakhah 6 note 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22550&pgnum=31)):

   > *ומיתת האזרחי מוכיח והוא הבשורה הטובה וכו׳*, פירש **מיתת אברהם** הנקרא איתן האזרחי **שמת בטבת** כנודע מספרי המקובלים בסוד תקבר בשבה טובה ר״ת למפרע טבת והוא הבשורה טובה כנודע, וזה שנרמז בו ר״ל בקרא כדפירשתי

   In my translation:

   > *And the death of the Ezrachi brings proof and it is the good announcement etc.*, [it has been] explained **the death of Avraham**, who is called *Eitan ha-Ezrachi*, **who died in *Tevet***, as is known from the books of the *Mequbalim*, is in the *Sod* of '*Tiqaver be-Seiva Tova*' ['thou shalt be buried in a good old age', [Bereshit 15:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0115.htm#15)], it's initials, from back to front, being *Tet*- *Bet*- *Tav*[ spelling *Tevet*] and this is the good announcement, as is known,and this is what is alluded to in it, i.e. in the writ, as I have interpreted.
3. The *Benei Yissakhar*, in [Regel Yesharah Ma'arekhet Tet No. 15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4759&pgnum=97), when bringing the *Sefer Qarnayim* and *Dan Yadin* about Avraham having died in *Tevet*, questions it, based on the *Machaloqet* in *Rosh ha-Shanah*, and answers that Avraham probably died in either *Tishrei* or *Nisan*, but was buried in *Tevet*. His reasoning is that the *Pasuq* used as proof-text for *Tevet* mentions *Qevurah*( burial), not death.

( It should be noted, that none of these sources give the exact date, but only the month, of Avraham's death.)

So, in conclusion we have:

1. *Tishrei*( R. Eli'ezer, in *Rosh ha-Shanah* 10b)
2. *Nisan*( R. Yehoshu'a, ibid. 11a)
3. *Tevet*( R. Shimshon ben Pesach Ostropoli, in *Dan Yadin*, though the *Benei Yissakhar* says he was only buried then)