# When is Avraham's birthday?

Tags: history, tanach, calendar, genealogy, abraham

I saw in a popular book a suggestion that Avraham was born on Rosh Chodesh Tevet. Does anyone have any backing sources for this?

Comment: See Gemara Rosh Hashana 11a: R' Eliezer holds he was born in Tishri, R' Yehoshua holds he was born in Nissan. (Exact dates not given)

Comment: From Bereshit 17:26, Rashi seems to suggest that Avraham Avinu and Ishmael had the same birthday. בעצם היום הזה. שֶׁמָּלְאוּ לְאַבְרָהָם צ"ט שָׁנָה וּלְיִשְׁמָעֵאל י"ג שָׁנִים נמול אברהם וישמעאל בנו:

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://rchaimqoton.blogspot.com/2007/04/happy-birthday.html) page (it is too much to simply copy and paste) speaks of the medrashic concept that the righteous die on their birthdays [scroll down to citation 27 in the text]. As such, acknowledging that Avraham Avinu was righteous, and the gemara mentions [possibilities](http://www.torahtots.com/timecapsule/thismonth/tevet.htm) for the Yahrzeit:

> Avraham Avinu (2124 - 1638 B.C.E.:), according to some sources (Bava Basra 91a). [According to others, Avrohom Avinu's Yartzeit is 1 Tishrei, or Nissan [Moed Katan 28a].

one could work backwards and derive a birthday commensurate with the death date one accepts.

---

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22101/when-is-avraham-avinus-yahrzeit) answer deals with the sources for the yahrzeit as well.

Comment: I'm not seeing any mention of the date of Avraham's passing in Bava Batra 91a. Your source appears to be unreliable.