# Zayin Adar customs

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, moshe-rabbeinu, adar

As tomorrow is Zayin Adar (and I'm a bit fed up with [PTIJ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest)), I was trying to find sources that Moses was born and died on Zayin Adar, and it was more difficult as it is widely known. For the record, it was already discussed on [Mi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88787/15256) [Yodea](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/moshe-rabeinus-yarzheit) based on [Kiddushin 38a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=38&format=pdf) and partially on [Sotah 13b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=13b&format=pdf). However, I know three customs (usually performed at the same event), but I don't know of sources citing them:

- Eat fish, since the gematria of דג is 'ז (see also for [Shabbath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/eating-fish-on-shabbos)) and the מזל of Adar is the fish (see [Rambam](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904969/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Three.htm))
- Commemorate the people, who deceased in the last year
- Collect funds for the Chevra Kadisha, since Hashem buried Moses (see [Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9998#showrashi=true) to Devarim 34:6 based on Sotah 13b)

Some others:

- Omit tachanun (a much [debated practice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55742/tachanun-on-7-adar) that is not mentioned in [Orach Chayim 131:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%95))
- Fast (see [Orach Chayim 580:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A4_%D7%91) and this [article](http://www.thejewishstar.com/stories/Observing-Moses-yartzeit-in-a-leap-year,2267))

Do you know any sources that mention them?

Comment: Downvoter, please comment...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is some minhag to skip Tachanun. I'll see if I can locate that. Even better see references mentioned in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55742/5275.

Comment: See ^^. If you feel like it, extract something from one of those refs, and post it as answer to your own question, here. I wonder if anyone added a minhag not to hit a rock with a stick :-)

Comment: @DanF According to [Sefer Haminhagim](http://chabadlibrarybooks.com/pdfpager.aspx?req=30479&st=%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8&pgnum=80&hilite=), there was a custom among the Chabad Rabbeim to not recite Tachanun on 7 Adar and the preceeding Mincha, but this was only after they assumed leadership, and never beforehand. The minhag in Lubavitch though is that we still say Tachanun, this custom was only recorded concerning the Rabbeim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73493/discussion-between-danf-and-ezra).

Answer (score 3):

[B'chedrei Charedim](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2586492&forum_id=20388) mentions the custom to fast on this day and say the "סדר תיקון ליום ז' אדר" . Just as the death of a tzaddik provides atonement, so does fasting with repentance.

The Chevra Kadisha make a festive meal on this day. This is because the members are happy when they have no work to do and Moshe was buried by HKB”H Himself.

[Yavnenet](http://www.yavnenet.co.il/article/48362) reports the custom of fasting etc. as above.

[Forum.otzar.org](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=8323) records the custom of fasting and mentions the surprising minhag of reading from the Torah from 'ויעל משה' to the end.

[Tehillim-center](https://www.tehillim-center.co.il/article/733) mentions segulos for this day which focus on prayer. The power of prayer on 7 Adar is especially powerful for women.

As is often said here, “absence of evidence is not evidence of absence”, so in summary all I can say is that I could not find references to the three customs although the Chevra Kadisha does get mentioned.

Comment: This answer is good, but I think it would be ideal if we could find a REAL source, like a sefer or something. Websites are less-than-ideal source material, even if what they say is true.

Comment: The chevra kaddisha minhag is quite common from what I understand. A few years ago, some of my local newspapers placed full page ads asking for donations for the chevra kaddisha on 7 Adar. It's a nice minhag, I think, for a group that does such important and difficult work.

Comment: cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114415/170